# Vim slow at rendering the buffer with LaTeX syntax highlighting

Tags: vim, gvim, latex, vim-plugins

After fixing a hard-drive failure, I am installing GVIM on my Thinkpad X230T laptop running Windows 10. Things are working well except for the rending speed of buffers for `*.tex` files. The problem is: with `syntax on`, the buffer of latex renders exceptionally slow. Here goes a list of "features":

1. It takes seconds to refresh a buffer of size 1920*1080 (in pixels) when I press `<C-f>`;
2. If I shrink the size of the buffer, the rendering gets faster. Still, I shall experience a second lag at minimum. During the lag, I can only see a blank buffer.
3. Text operations are also slow. Simply starting a new line below by pressing `o` shall also end up with a one-second-lag. This is largely due to the rendering of the whole buffer after adding that single line: all the lines that follows shall be refreshed for their "new" position.

As sample screencast:
[image]

I have applied all the suggested options mentioned in this post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8300982/vim-slow-running-latex-files), yet I still get the same slow rendering speed.

I was only experiencing this exceptional slowdown on my X230T. With exactly the same `_vimrc` on the other two desktop machines, I don't even experience a tiny lag in the rendering speed. Nor did I experience the rendering problem with previous installation of Windows 7 and 8 on the same X230T laptop.

Lastly, for hard drive, I am having a SSD on my X230T, which worked pretty well so far; and I have HDD on both the other two desktop machines.

Any advice would be very helpful!

Thanks a lot!

All the best,

-Linfeng

Comment: Did you figure this out in the end? I have the same on a x230t running OpenBSD.

Comment: @EddBarrett, No, I have not. What I end up doing is to use Remote Desktop Connection on my X230T laptop to access my home desktop machine, which displays no delay at rendering. It may just be that X230T is too old for modern operating systems. (I definitely have no problem with rendering *.tex files when I was using Windows 7 and Windows 8.1). Good luck on your side.

Comment: I find that turning syntax highlighting off helps.

Comment: Definitely! Thanks a lot! I have been setting the filetype to null for a while :)

Comment: Try opening the file with: `vim -u NONE filename.tex` to disable your .vimrc and other scripts from loading for the session. If this helps, see [this method](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12216578/165358) for finding out where exactly is the slow-down.

Comment: @harrymc, my Vim loads `*.tex` files with no delay when starting with options "-u NONE"; and have tried to log the "profile". Yet, the output "profile.log" is rather complicated, and I cannot find a function that is called for "rendering" the buffer. Do you have an idea which function I shall look into?

Comment: To clarify: Does "-u NONE" fix the problem even if syntax highlighting is ON?

Comment: Yes, the option "-u NONE" fixes the rendering problem, even if the Syntax highlighting is ON.

Comment: Then the vimrc file initiates the slow-down. Try to selectively delete parts of it to find out where exactly is the cause (take backup).

Comment: @EddBarrett, have you tried to decipher the output from `profile`-ing? Mine is quite confusing, and I don't find a specific log that records the number of page rendering. I guess this is machine-specific: some hardware of the X230T is no longer compatible with the "major" Vim distribution, maybe?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is, vim's regular expression engine is really slow, and I guess latex is pretty demanding on regex.

I was able to get vim a bit faster by doing:

```
:syn clear texSectionFold
:syn clear texPreamble
```

These were the main offending syntax group regexes.

I found them by doing:

```
:syntime on
```

Now press `ctrl+L` a ton of times and wait for vim to catch up. Then:

```
:syntime report
```

This gave the following output:

```
  TOTAL      COUNT  MATCH   SLOWEST     AVERAGE   NAME               PATTERN
  8.903872   1911   52      0.017387    0.004659  texSectionFold     \v%(%(\\begin\{document\}.*$\n)@<=^|\\section)
  4.979438   1859   0       0.016382    0.002679  texPreamble        \v%(\\documentclass)@=
  0.634906   1976   182     0.010863    0.000321  texEnvName         \v%(\\%(begin|end)\{)@<=\a+\*?\ze\}
  0.373173   1859   0       0.000880    0.000201  texArgsEnvNormReq  \v(\\begin\{%(theorem|lemma|proposition|corollary|conjecture|definition|remark|example|proof)\*?\}\s*)@<=\{
  0.317732   1859   0       0.000468    0.000171  texArgsEnvNormOpt  \v(\\begin\{%(theorem|lemma|proposition|corollary|conjecture|definition|remark|example|proof)\*?\}\s*)@<=\[
  0.223595   1859   0       0.000341    0.000120  texDimen           \v-?%(\.[0-9]+|([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?))%(pt|pc|bp|in|cm|mm|dd|cc|sp|ex|em)>
...
```

So you can see that those two regexes are way more expensive than others. I don't use folds, so I had no issue disabling that. Not sure why finding the preamble is so slow.

Perhaps this helps you too, @llinfeng. I hope so!

EDIT:

To run those `syn clear` commands when vim starts, you would need to put them in `~/.vim/after/syntax/tex.vim`. It won't work in an `ftplugin` file, as the syntax definitions are not yet loaded at that point.

EDIT2:

Turns out some of the syntax groups I posted above came from a plugin. Disabling the plugin doesn't help, as then some other syntax groups are slow. Eesh!

My final fix, and all I ask from syntax highlight, is:

```
$ cat ~/.vim/after/syntax/tex.vim 
syn clear
syn match texComment   "%.*$"                                            
hi def link texComment  Comment
```

It's really fast.

Comment: Hi @Edd, thanks a lot! My `syntime report` is more unfriendly, as you may see here https://www.dropbox.com/s/guxzuqcuu2p510n/syntime_report_Tex.png?dl=0 The difference is that, my slow-down of rendering may be attributed to literally all display options. I will now look for a way to only "paint color" for math expressions.

Comment: Glad that helped. I still feel like something is wrong with vim if these modern machines can't run a few regexs. FWIW, I also tried with neovim, and it was the same there.

Comment: Hi @Edd, here goes the minimum syntax highlighting file that I created, it has more *color* in it (yet, as I don't have much understanding of the syntax highlighting, it may be crappy in all possible ways):  https://github.com/llinfeng/Vim/blob/X230T/vimfiles/after/syntax/tex.vim

Answer (score 1):

You have used `vim -u NONE filename.tex` when opening the file to disable your `.vimrc` and other scripts from loading for the session, and this has fixed the problem.

The conclusion is that something started by the `.vimrc` file causes the slow-down.

Try to selectively delete parts of the file to find out what exactly is the cause.
Remember to take a backup.

Comment: As mentioned above, it is the syntax colouring built into vim that causes the issue, not a plugin.

Comment: @EddBarrett: I am confused between you and llinfeng. He says that without .vimrc syntax highlighting is fast enough. I don't know what causes the slow-down in his .vimrc, but you could check if it's the same with yours. I cannot check it, as I don't use latex.

Comment: Without .vimrc you don't get any syntax highlighting, You need `:set syntax=on` in the vimrc.

Comment: @EddBarrett: One can probably turn this on also during execution, but one good test could be to use a .vimrc that just has this line. In any case, I counseled recreating the file in stages until the problem reappears (if it truly does disappear as I was told).

Answer (score 1):

## Partial Solution for Thinkapd X230T per se

### Problem Identification

As @Edd has suggested, use `:syntime on` and `syntime report` to identify the most time-consuming syntax-highlighting "group/region/match"';

### Partial Solution

As to be found in the following URL, I have loaded the `tex.vim` in the `after` directory of my Vim distribution (`c:\vim\vimfiles\after\syntax\` for my case):

https://github.com/llinfeng/Vim/blob/X230T/vimfiles/after/syntax/tex.vim

### Outcome

Using the same LaTeX file, my improved performance goes as follows

[image: Improved Performance]

### Open question --- how to replicate the syntax-highlighting effeciently

The syntax coloring is not ideal, as compared to the native `tex.vim` to be found as `c:\vim\vim80\syntax\tex.vim`.